# Issue linking CSS to backend Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

I am working on a `Zend Framework  1` application. It is successfully installed on my `localhost` and is working without any problems. However I've noticed that the `css` for the back end of the application is not working.

When I view the page source I can see the `stylesheet` has been loaded and can click on the link to it to view in the browser.

However the style is not applied to any of the elements on the screen and I do not understand why.

This is the layout file for the page: (adminstyle.css is not loading...)

```
        <link href="/css/adminstyle.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="default" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_2.ico" />
    </head>
```

does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Apologies for the question if it seems stupid but I'm not really experienced with this sort of thing and I am trying to get to the bottom of it. Any help is much appreciated.

I can provide more details if required, I just do not want to post lots of unescessary snippets of code up.

Comment: Is /css located within your webroot? That tag is also missing the ending slash.

Comment: Can you give us a sample HTML part of styled element and css part that styles it.

Comment: @JasonRice I fixed the ending slash, thank you for spotting and with regards to `/css` it is in the `public` directory of the project in the webroot yes

Comment: If you can view the stylesheet by viewing source and clicking the link (as you said), this is not a PHP/ZF problem. There is either an issue with the stylesheet itself, or the rules within it are not being applied to your HTML for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to write links in zend framework cause with your way it will work just for the index/index , for other view you won't get the style css applied :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl()."/css/style.css"; ?>" >
```

the same for your js files 
hope it helps.